# Why time complexity of following code is O(n^2)?

Tags: c++, c, time-complexity

```
void level_order_recursive(struct node *t , int h) //'h' is height of my binary tree
{                                                 //'t' is address of root node
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= h ; i++)  
    {
        print_level(t , i);
    }
}
```

> After print_level() is called everytime , I think recursive function is called (2^i) times . So 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 ....2^h should give time complexity of O(2^n).Where am I going wrong ?

```
void print_level(struct node * t , int i)
{
    if( i == 0)
        cout << t -> data <<" ";
    else
        {
            if(t -> left != NULL)
                print_level(t -> left , i - 1);   //recursive call
            if(t -> right != NULL)
                print_level(t -> right , i - 1); //recursive call
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the "data" you are printing here: cout << t -> data <<" "; ? should it be complexity values? Also, why do you think you are wrong? It's indeed O(2^n) from your calculation.

Comment: @meJustAndrew Its an integer data . That is defined in node structure that I have not mentioned here . Its recursive version of Level order traversal of a binary tree. Time complexity of this code is supposed to be O(n^2). Can you please check it out  [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always start at the root of the tree `t` and increase the level by one each time (`i`) until you reach the height of the tree `h`.

You said it is a binary tree, but you did not mention any property, e.g. balanced or so. So I assume it can be an unbalanced binary tree and thus the height of the tree in worst case can be `h = n` where `n` is the number of nodes (that is a completely unbalanced tree that looks like a list actually).

So this means that `level_order_recursive` loops `n` times. I.e. the worst case is that the tree has `n` levels.

`print_level` receives the root node and the level to print. And it calls itself recursively *until it reaches the level* and prints out that level.
I.e. it *loops* `i` times (a recursive call decreases `i` by one each time).

So you have `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + h` iterations. And since `h = n` you get `1 + 2 + 3 ... + n` steps. This is `(n * (n+1))/2` (Gaussian sum formula) which is in `O(n^2)`.

If you can assure that the tree is balanced than you would improve the worst case scenario, because the height would be `h = ld(n)` where *ld* denotes the binary logarithm.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing h and n. h is the height of the tree. n is apparently the number of elements in the tree. So print_level takes worst case O ($2^i), but that is also just n.

The worst case happens when you have a degenerate tree, where each node has only one successor. In that case you have n nodes, but the height of the tree is also h = n. Each call to print_level takes i steps in that case, and summing up i from 1 to h = n gives O ($n^2).

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/kruse/cs240/recsearch.htm) or [that](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~saia/classes/561-f13/lec/lec3.pdf), pages 3 and 4, binary search algorithm, which resembles our case, has a time complexity of `T(n) = T(n/2) + c`.
Except that, both left and right sub-trees are browsed, hence the 2T(n/2) in the formula below, since this is a traversal algorithm, rather than a search one.

Here, I will comply to the question and use 'h' instead of 'n'.

Using recurrence relation, you get the following proof:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't make much sense with out a bit explanation.

Comment: I "foreworded" my response with an explanation. Please do let me know if you it needs more details.

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case the time complexity will be O(n^2) but cannot be 2^n as time complexity for each level will be-> O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + ... + O(1) which is at worst O(n^2).

Comment: How is time complexity of each level is linear ? Like O(n) . Can you explain ?